# Most efficient way for storing geolocations in a database

Tags: database, geolocation, geocoding

I know postgres has a datatype for storing geographical coordinates. But I'm looking for a RDBMS-agnostic solution. Currently I'm using `Decimal(25,20)` in MySQL. I may be using this data to lookup these locations based on a given distance from a given location later. Which would be the best approach to store this kind of data?

Answer (score 7):

Another good technique is to multiply the values by a constant and store them as integer values.  Using integers only can also help speed up calculations.

Unless you are in serious need of precision you should really only need to store 5+ values after the decimal point.

This [Latitude Longitude Data Storage Specification](http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/rpm-gbi/guides/Latlong_e.asp) gives a chart that shows precision vs decimal places.

```
# decmal places, example, precision
5    51.22135    ± 0.8 m
6   50.895132   ± 0.08 m
```

7 would work out to be 8mm, or about 0.314 inches.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is [here](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=18241). Although it's too much for a simple use case such as yours, it may give you some ideas about why it may actually be best to go and use some OGC compliant packages many databases have nowadays, even [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html).

Failing that, and assuming you will implement the algorithms for distance calculations, any floating point number that has the precision you need will work.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, MS SQL Server 2008 has support for GeoLocations as a DataType.  I know you are using MySQL, but just thought I'd mention it on this question.

Comment: The DataTypes are GEOGRAPHY and GEOMETRY. He would want to use GEOGRAPHY.

Answer (score 1):

[vfilby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293997/most-efficient-way-for-storing-geolocations-in-a-database#294014) is probably the best one, however many RDBMS have better support for indexing *character* fields than indexing *dense* integer (or floating point) fields.

For this reason alone, I might recommend transforming the data first: If you want to find values "near" another value, you'll additionally want a function that preserves this- perhaps by converting to base36 and `_`-padding to the decimal point, but if you just need an exact match, nearly any fast hashing function will do.

Again: If you don't have a lot of data, or you're not using an RDBMS like this, do what [vfilby suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293997/most-efficient-way-for-storing-geolocations-in-a-database#294014).

Answer (score 0):

Following @[vfilby's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293997/most-efficient-way-for-storing-geolocations-in-a-database#294014) answer, why not store the two halves of the number as two separate int types?

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used 4-byte floating point columns to save latitude and longitude, because the error in precision is much less than the accuracy of the devices we use.  This may not be the case with your application, but if it is you can't get much more RDBMS-agnostic than a float.